# IIS hosted Web Application cannot accessible through Internet

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, iis

I have hosted Flask Web application on Windows Server on AWS, I have done followings

- hosted it on IIS and add new bindings(port 8090) to web site
- Created inbound rule for the port(8090) given in bindings

And it works fine on the server, but when i'm trying to access it on my PC's web browser says
`it cannot reach took too long to respond`

What else i need to do ?

Comment: You need to check your server logs and look for clues there - we can only guess at what's needed with the provided information.  Please read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question

Comment: For starters, how are you trying to access it from your PC?

Comment: @blurfus Server Ip address and port <ipaddress>:8090

Comment: is the IP address accessible from outside the AWS network? can you ping it?

Comment: @blurfus cannot

Comment: in IIS im only able to assign private IP of server,

Comment: then that's your issue, it seems. You cannot reach the IP from your computer - it explains the time out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240257/discussion-between-pl-jay-and-blurfus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your vm, different provider has their security policy. For aws even you have set inbound port rule, it will not work. You also need to set inbound rules in their potal.**

(1) [Open Windows firewall, Create an Inbound Port Rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-port-rule).

(2) [Directly in Amazon Web Service console, exactly in security groups/inbound](https://intellipaat.com/community/3913/ec2-how-to-add-port-8080-in-security-group).