# Portal access using IP Error: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, firewall, elastic-ip

I have a local web site hosted on Windows 2019 EC2 Instance. This ec2 instance has a public IP (Elastic IP Address). The public IP is ping-able from out of the ec2 instance.
I am able to access the portal using the below from the same EC2 Instance

```
http://{Public IPv4 DNS}/Login.asp  (Working on the Ec2)

http://{localhost}/Login.asp        (Working on the Ec2)

http://{PrivateIP}/Login.asp        (Working on the Ec2)

http://{PublicIP}/Login.asp         (Not working, error: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)
```

Added the FQDN to the Host file and also added
[image]
In the Ec2 Instance security group, added the inbound rule with the port (80),Protocol TCP and the public IP

I want to access the the portal using the public IP from out of the EC2 Instance. I am not sure what I missed in the configuration. Thank you.

Comment: Windows Server also has Windows Firewall enabled by default, so you need to open port 80 there.

Comment: Make sure that: 1) you are using correct IP address in your browser.  2) security group attached to your EC2 instance has port 80 open. 3) server is listening on port 80. 4) OS firewall is stopped, or has port 80 open.

Comment: [You need to check security group in your portal.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70406200/iis-hosted-web-application-cannot-accessible-through-internet/70416717#70416717)